# problem displaying unicode using Spring MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, unicode

I am trying to display some nepali langauage charcaters in my spring MVC webapp with freemarker,

i did everything like i have character encoding filter in my web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
```

My freemarker configuration is like

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="prefix" value=""/>
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
        <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

and in template i have

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

defined i just see some weird charcaters in my page. Thought the response header has the 
correct content type "text/html; charset=UTF-8"

Not sure what and where's the problem. I even tried to set the content type from the 
controller response.setContentType('text/html; charset=UTF-8");

Help guys

Comment: where is your content from?  is your datasource in a format or type that supports extended character sets?

Comment: actually i am trying to read from messages.properties file using 
<@spring.message code='error-input'/> tag

Comment: Are you positive that the messages.properties file is itself UTF-8 encoded? There is a good chance (if you're on Windows), that it's actually ISO 8859-1. Could you give an example of a character you expect to see as well as what you are actually seeing?

Comment: i am on a mac i have a propety like Jestha.nepali=बैशाख in messages.properties but i am getting  à¤¬à¥à¤¶à¤¾à¤ in my page.

Comment: my properties file is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Properties files loaded through java.util.Properties are always in iso-8859-1, and need to have characters from other character sets written in escape format- "\u20AC" etc.

Answer (score 4):

ok i fixed this issue, i used ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource instead of ResourceBundleMessageSource with property defaultEncoding to UTF-8 so
also had to add classpath for basename property value.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
<property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

it works now..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the content is correct?  Perhaps it's not valid UTF-8.

Are the "weird" characters only at the very beginning?  Then they could be Windows formatted UTF-8 BOM (byte order marking).

Comment: i am on mac but looks like it's something to do with my eclipse file and content type association .